# Android Volley Post Error

Tags: android, post, server, android-volley

I have an error. I send data to server but this code is not working.
Please help me for this. Thanks.   I have simple login method. That is working but this is not working. Where is the error.

@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

```
        StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, new AppData().MUSTERI_KAYIT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                            Log.i(" ADD CUSTOMER RESPONSE - ", response);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(" ADD CUSTOMER RESPONSE ERROR ", e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("volley", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                error.printStackTrace();
                snackBar();
                Log.e(" --- ", error.toString());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
                    VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                    volleyError = error;
                    Log.d(" Errrrorrrrr - ", volleyError.toString());
                }
                return volleyError;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String auth = "Bearer " + access_token;
                params.put("Authorization", auth);
                params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                params.put("accounttype", editMusteriTipi.getText().toString());
                params.put("title", editUnvan.getText().toString());

                params.put("phone", editPhone.getText().toString());
                params.put("email", editEMail.getText().toString());
                params.put("tckn", editTcKimlikNo.getText().toString());

                params.put("city", editCity.getText().toString());
                params.put("district", editIlce.getText().toString());
                params.put("addressdetail", editAdress.getText().toString());
                //params.put("Vinno", editAracNo.getText().toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < sektorList.size(); i++) {
                    if (sektorList.get(i).getName().equals(editSektor.getText().toString())) {
                        params.put("sector", sektorList.get(i).getId());
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < kategoriList.size(); i++) {
                    if (kategoriList.get(i).getName().equals(editKategori.getText().toString())) {
                        params.put("category", kategoriList.get(i).getId());
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < vergiDairesiList.size(); i++) {
                    if (vergiDairesiList.get(i).getName().equals(editVergiDairesi.getText().toString())) {

                    }
                }
                params.put("vd", editVergiDairesi.getText().toString());
                params.put("vdno", editVergiDairesiNo.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CustomerRecord.this);
        queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
        return null;
    }
```

And below code is error.

```
E/ ---: com.android.volley.VolleyError: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
    fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
    h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
    h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
    h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
    #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
    background-color:#555555;}
    #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
    .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
    <div id="content">
     <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
      <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
      <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
     </fieldset></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And below error,

```
E/Volley: [514] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://....
```

I search how can i fix this but i was not found that

Comment: used retrofit 2.0 it is easy and latest for devloper.

Comment: I agree with above comment. You can use retrofit 2.0, its highly beneficial. By looking at the error , `Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` it looks like you are missing some auth key. Also if you expect your response in JSON, use `JsonRequst` instead `StringRequest`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used okhttp and i resolved post problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
/** Your login API response is an HTML error.

     1. You should before test the API with Postman if is working properly.
     2. Then I suggest you to print on Logcat the request you are doing from you're app. Based on you're code:   **/


                 Log.d("LOGIN_REQ" , AppData().MUSTERI_KAYIT);
                     StringRequest jsonObjRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, new AppData().MUSTERI_KAYIT,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                 .....                    
            }

            .....

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String auth = "Bearer " + access_token;
                    params.put("Authorization", auth);
                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    ....
                    ....
                    Log.d("LOGIN_REQ",params);
                    return params;
                }

            };



/**    
3. Another think based on my little backend experience you are sending the 
        Authorization and the Content type as parameters in the request body. The 
        Authorization and the Content type are headers. So using volley you should 
        override another method:



   **/

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
      Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      String auth = "Bearer " + access_token;
      params.put("Authorization", auth);
      params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      return params;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used okhttp and i resolved post problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Retrofit in order to avoid this kind of problems. 
You will write less code but get a lot.

Here is the main difference two mainly used techniques for implementing API’s is our android app. You can see the difference in performance that for one discussion means for one network request and response they will take how much time.

**Volley**

1. one(1) discussion: 560 ms
2. Seven(7) discussions: 2202 ms
3. Twenty Five(25) discussions: 4275 ms

**Retrofit**

1. one(1) discussion: 312 ms
2. Seven(7) discussions: 889 ms
3. Twenty Five(25) discussions: 1059 ms

Original post [here](https://abhiandroid.com/programming/retrofit)

**Tutorials for learning Retrofit**

I found following tutorials to be effective to learn basics of Retrofit

1. https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23
2. https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used okhttp and i resolved post problem.